# Caching images and then rendering cached images in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, image, caching

I have a `.json` file in this format:

```
[
    {
        "graph":"https://foo.com/img1.png" 
    },
    {
        "graph":"https://foo.com/img3.png" 
    },
    {
        "graph":"https://foo.com/img3.png" 
    }
]
```

Now when I obtain this file I have to put all the images into cache (`$angularCacheFatory`) and once done then I render the view. 
Something like this:

```
ServiceName.getJSONFile().then(function(data){
    var x = data;
     $scope.myImages = data;

    // Download x.graph and then insert it into the cache
    x.forEach(function(item, index, array){
         $http.get(item.graph).then(function(res){
             imageCache.put('x.graph', res);
         });
    })

});
```

Now after I have cached it, how do I obtain the cached image in the view?

```
 <img ng-src={{myImages.graph}} >
```

This simply does not work. Am I doing anything wrong?

Edit:

Overall objective:

First fetch the images listed in the URL. Then store the images in the cache. Then render the image that is in the cache.

When I render the view, I don't want to fetch the image over the network. I want to display the image that is in the cache. Hence before rendering the view I am pre-loading all the images and then inserting it into the cache so that `ng-src={{path}}` fetches locally cached images.

Comment: `myImages` is an array of objects, not clear what your overall objective is but try `{{myImages[0].graph}}`

Comment: Hey I will edit. Have a look at overall objective now. And I don't need array notation cos it is a ng-repeat.

Comment: Images are rendered by the browser, i dont think you can do anything with the angular cache... You may want to preload the images in a temporary img tag and img has onload event which you can register and return promise and resolve it once all the images have been loaded completely(If that is what you need). Whatever be the case images would need to be loaded once from the network.. and once it is loaded browser in its default setting will have them cached

Comment: "You may want to preload the images in a temporary img tag and img has onload event which you can register and return promise and resolve it once all the images have been loaded completely(If that is what you need)."     Can you explain this to me in a bit more detail?

Comment: function preloadImage(url)
{
    var img=new Image();
    img.src=url;
}

Comment: Ok so I do this and then the service returns and the controller starts running and the view is rendered. Now in my view I have <img ng-src="myImgages.graph"> does the image come from cache or over the netowrk?

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same problem. can you tell me how solve it please. ?